# Spring 4 MVC JSR303 @Valid error message to property

Tags: java, spring

Trying to have all of my error message in a property.

Following tutorial: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/

Problem:  Error message is not coming from my property file.  Not sure what I am doing wrong

File Structure:

[image]

POJO

```
import javax.validation.constraints.DecimalMin;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name="books")
public class Book implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2042607611480064259L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@NotNull
@Size(min=7)
private String name;

@NotNull
@Size(min=2, max=13)
private String ispn;

@DecimalMin(value = "0.01")
private double price;

public Book(){}


//   Setter & getters

}
```

exception_en_US.properties

```
NotNull.book.name = Book name must not be blank, Please insert valid book name.
Size.book.name = Book name should have more than 7 characters.

NotNull.book.ispn = Must enter valid ISPN code.
Size.book.ispn = Standard ISPN code should have 10, 13 characters.

DecimalMin.book.price = Price of the book must be greater than 0. And can not be Negative number.
```

app-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.controller" />

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

<!-- Binding properties to context -->

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>com.app.properties.windows</value>
            <value>com.app.properties.exceptions</value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>
```

What am I doing wrong? Your extra eye is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can I send it to my mailbox? Thank you

Comment: Because my eclipse plugin is always not installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out `exception_en_US.properties` shouldn't reference the class and field but form & path name, form name, which is given by commandName or modelAttribute.

This is my HTML

```
<sf:form action="/newbook" modelAttribute="formBook" method="POST">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Book Name:</td>
            <td>
                <sf:input type='text' name='name' path="name"/><br/>
                <sf:errors path="name"></sf:errors>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ispn:</td>
            <td>
                <sf:input type='text' name='ispn' path="ispn"/><br/>
                <sf:errors path="ispn"></sf:errors> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Price:</td>
            <td>
                <sf:input type='text' name='price' path="price"/><br/>
                <sf:errors path="price"></sf:errors>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/></td></tr>

        </table>
    </sf:form>
```

Notice:   `modelAttribute="formBook"`

So in my `exception_en_US.properties`

```
NotNull.formBook.name = Book name must not be blank, Please insert valid book name.
Size.formBook.name = Book name should have more than 7 characters.

NotNull.formBook.ispn = Must enter valid ISPN code.
Size.formBook.ispn = Standard ISPN code should have 10, 13 characters.
```

Hope this helps others... took me soo sooo long ...

Answer (score 1):

I think your messageSource configuration is wrong. Try something like this:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:window</value>
            <value>classpath:exception</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I thought the value needs to be qualify name... EDIT:  I tried, this didn't work .  When I did this window.properties was not loading..... Do you need me to take a screen shot of my folders?  would that help?

Comment: OK, please do so.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time I have uploaded the file structure...  So my code nothing looks wrong?